# Converting non-continuous angle to 360

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

I have a computer program which outputs an unusual angle system.

All angles on the left are $0$ (top) to $-180$ degrees (bottom) and all angles on the right are $0$ (top) to $+180$ (bottom)

Is there a straightforward mathematical way to convert this system into $0$ to $360$ angles?  For example, $0$ on top and increasing clockwise from there toward $360$ degrees?

Comment: Depends on where you want the zero and in what direction you want the angles to increase. But the simplest thing would be to just add 180. Then the bottom is 0 and angles increase clockwise.

Comment: The answer below fixed the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, your current angle measures look like this:

```
    -1  1  
 -90     90
  -179 179
```

To convert the above to

```
   359  1  
 270     90
   181 179
```

you can use the formula 
$$
y = \begin{cases} x,\quad &\text{if } x\ge 0 \\ 360-x \quad & \text{if }x<0\end{cases}
$$

Or you could convert to counterclockwise variant

```
    1  359  
  90     270
   179  181
```

with 
$$
y = \begin{cases} 360 - x,\quad &\text{if } x> 0 \\ -x \quad & \text{if }x\le 0\end{cases}
$$